# TortoiseSVN localhost or hosts file lookup is slower than IP lookup Windows 10

Tags: svn, localhost, tortoisesvn, ipv4

I have TortoiseSVN correctly configured on my Windows10 x64 machines at home and have used TSVN for many years with the file://xxx access method to repositories. Now, I am trying to move to the `svn://<IPv4>/xxx` and the `svn://<hostname>/xxx` methods.

The `svn://<IPv4>/xxx` works correctly and immediately, probably because TSVN does not have to do any network lookups.

But the `svn://localhost/xxx` syntax is slow because it waits for a timeout somewhere. After the timeout expires, the repo browser loads the repository as usual.

My Windows hosts file has `127.0.0.1 localhost` uncommented, as well as other entries for other machines on my home network. I want to think that TSVN would look in the local System32/drivers/etc/hosts file before trying (and failing) to find "localhost" through the DHCP-configured DNS addresses for my ISP. But I suppose I could be wrong about that.

I have searched the net and this website, but have not found anything that matches my scenario (which, I would think, is a common scenario on a home network with more than one machine for dev).

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get the `svn://<hostname>/xxx` syntax method working on my home network? (I'm tired of memorizing specific IP addresses for machines, and tired of waiting for timeouts to perform SVN operations.) Thank you.

Comment: What SVN client and `svnserve` version do you use? BTW, consider installing [VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/). Installation, set up and overall maintenance is very simple and straightforward. See the Getting Started guide at https://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/

Comment: I have the latest versions of everything from TortoiseSVN (it includes the command line tools like svnserve). I do use VisualSVN in VStudio. I haven't looked at the VisualSVN server. In other news, I have one machine that has no delay with the ```svn://<hostname>/xxx``` syntax. Strange. It has the same entries in the Windows hosts file that the other machine has.

Comment: I don’t think that the problem is with dns or hosts file. Check your antivirus and firewall. Antivirus applications can cause delays because of traffic interception.

Answer (score 0):

The delay has gone away now. I think it must have been a router DHCP lease or something. Since I posted the question a day has gone by and I have rebooted and reassigned static IP addresses. Now `svn://<hostname>/xxx` works without big delays on all machines.